# Most hospitable biomes for living off the land

Tags: environment, survival, alternate-earth, colonization

I'm trying to figure out which are the most hospitable biomes for living off the land.

Say we have a small spacecraft fallen through a time warp that takes it sideways in time, where it finds itself in orbit around an uninhabited planet. For the purposes of this question, suppose the planet is 'present-day Earth, except humans never lived here'. So interglacial period with the same geography, there are still passenger pigeons in North America etc.

The crew need to pick a spot to land, before their oxygen runs out. Once down, they will not have fuel to take off again, so they will be stuck trying to survive wherever they are.

They have some relevant training in wilderness survival. They also have electronic devices with extensive tutorials etc. They have only minimal, basic tools. They don't have seeds or domestic animals, so at least for the first while, they will be relying on hunting and gathering, not agriculture.

Let's give them a break and assume the time of year is whatever would make it easiest for them to get started – northern hemisphere spring?

Where should they land?

Comment: What should be a long term strategy for these survivors? Do they want to start a successful civilization, or just hold on for short while, expecting a rescue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### someplace warm to temperate, with mountains on the east coast of a land mass.

they should be more worried about access to wood, metal and coal. survival can be done in a lot of places, but not everywhere has abundant resources for tools. You plan for the long term or risk dooming themselves to technological stagnation. many places ran into limitation due to limited access to timber or or metals.

they also need to worry about water, since they will not have water purification, so you want someplace with abundant ground water so they can dig a well.

If you are using actual earth they should land where domesticable plants and animals are. A place that is good now but also good for their future. happily such places that also have abundant food exist, Anywhere you have mountains on the eastern coast of a continent that is fed by prevailing wind from the ocean.

[image]

(image from https://globalplantcouncil.org/)

All in all the eastern US or coastal China is your best bet, lots of rivers and rain, abundant forests, mineral deposits, and abundant food. What do these two places have in common, **a temperate to warm climate combines with lots of mountains on the eastern coast of a land mass, which means lots of rain and lots of exposed mineral deposits. which means lots of river, high grade soil and thus lots of food.**

The US used to have lots of American chestnut trees, which was fast growing, produces excellent timber, and produced so many seeds it was incredibly easy to farm and produced literally tons of food. enough to support humans and abundant wildlife in their ranges.  Even better since they drop in the fall they provided abundant food exactly when it was most needed. (to the point it may become the first genetically engineered organism purposely introduced to the wild with the intention of breeding in order to bring it back)

without humans the US would also still have horse and camel species, as well as a slew of other animals that might be domesticable if they can resist hunting them to extinction.

Alternatively china gets you basically everything the western US will get you plus pigs and water buffalo, so you get a leg up on domestication, especially something that can pull a plow or wagon.

What do these two places have in common, **a temperate to warm climate combines with lots of mountains on the eastern coast of a land mass, which means lots of rain and lots of mineral deposits.**

temperate climates have the advantage of vastly lower pest and disease occurrence, the downside is a limited growing season. generally you want a climate that is mild and not too hot or too cold.

Comment: New Zealand should be 3/4 yellow

Comment: The Americas never had horses until they were introduced by the Europeans, basically there were very few crops or animals that could be domesticated.  The Fertile Crescent was the cradle of civilisation for a reason, and prior to it being over-farmed it had forests.  China is a good second choice.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 Horses evolved in North America, were exterminated along with 90% of the megafauna that had the bad luck of encountering Homo Sapiens before anything else from the human family. Eurasian and African animals learned to fear out weaker relatives. Horses were reintroduced by humans. The only chance for American horses to survive would be if an earlier human species makes it to the Americas.

Comment: @SeanOConnor, why? New Zealand is mostly pastoralism with feed bought from other countries.

Comment: NZ is almost entirely grass fed (there has been some palm kernel feed brought in in recent years), and it's generally considered to have the most productive and efficient agricultural sector in the world (in dollar terms). If pretty much anywhere in Europe is yellow (the UK? Up to Scotland?), then NZ should be. There's a reason it's able to export ludicrous amounts of food with zero subsidies. I live here; you can grow absolutely anything, bar tropical fruit. I've lived in Australia and visited Europe; you can see the difference in the productivity of the land with no training at all.

Comment: @SeanOConnor you can say that about any good farmland, which new Zealand has little of, and again the agricultural sector is productive because they produce mostly meat and dairy via imported feed. more than 60% of NZ animal feed is imported. If NZ had to produce it on their own it would be just another swath of mediocre farmland. comparing small patched of land is not going to give you an idea of overall productivity, anecdotal evidence is not evidence.. NZ is not even in the top ten for most agriculturally productive country.

Comment: @SeanOConnor I wonder if you count in dollars, whether the outcome will represent agricultural potential, because food prices in NZ are relatively high https://www.theglobaleconomy.com/rankings/food_price_index_wb/

Comment: Relatively? They're extortionate. But that's because we pay export grade prices for everything. It's almost a pure free market (and the supermarkets are a duopoly). We have to pay what the UK does for lamb, what Japan does for kiwifruit, what the US does for wine, and what China's wealthy do for everything, or it's not sold here. If you want hard data, go compare Canterbury wheat yields to the Australian ones from your map (you can see nice maps on Google). Look, in the end, if I can't persuade you a huge food exporter with gorgeous soil really is more productive than Scotland, well, so be it.

Comment: @John, yes, most feed is imported, but 90% of the calories isn't from feed at all. It's from grass, which doesn't count as 'feed'. Look at the notes from whatever data table you're looking at. Exporting 45 million peoples food with 5 million population isn't 'anecdotal'. But believe what you like pal, if you want to beclown yourself thinking Scotland and Australia's land is productive compared to NZ, be my guest, this is an internet forum, I can't stop you. Don't let people who have lived in the regions involved tell you better, and definitely don't look at wheat yields per hectare.

Comment: @Goodies, sorry, I wasn't meaning to be so abrasive to you; you're not pontificating about an industry you've no idea about in places you haven't been to to someone who is and has.

Comment: @Goodies I suggest dollars per hectare or dollars per capita are the best measure of land productivity. TFP is dumb because a third world country with zero labour costs, worthless land and no capital goods looks amazingly productive despite eking out some pathetic yield. Other methods are to take a single product and look at yield per hectare. There are probably calorie per hectare figures but they'll distort in favour of grain over better land that is used for premium crops, horticulture, etc.

Comment: @John Read this. Note the paragraphs on pasture versus feed. https://mpi.govt.nz/dmsdocument/20897-Feed-use-in-the-NZ-dairy-industry/sitemap. Alternatively, look up per hectare feed yields. TFP is a stupid, totally misleading metric (zero labour cost, worthless land, no tractor + 6 beans per hectare = "so productive!" and if you'd thought about it for a minute, you'd have realised the Wikipedia tables you presumably looked up don't match the map you've provided. You're the mirror image of a rural person who insists that you can't tell New York is bigger than Pittsburgh just by living there.

Comment: @Goodies 1 I showed were I got the data Wikipedia was not involved, If you have a problem with it take it up with them. 2 your own data shows imported feed in increasing as a a percentage of dairy feed, it doesn't cover the largest industry sheep and beef cattle, doesn't distinguish between imported pasture feed and native pasture feed, imported hay is still "pasture feed".  For instance in 2018 NZ produced 1.89 million metric tons of animal feed and imported 5.5 million metric tons. Agriculture may be an important industry to NZ but it is an import dependent industry

Comment: @Goodies this is not surprising many places have such agriculture and it is nothing to be ashamed of, few places on the planet have high fertility soil that is also high resilience soil at the same time, which is why few places have high historic productivity and high modern productivity. There would likely be none without modern fertilizers.

Comment: Pasture and feed are mutually exclusive in agriculture terminology. "Pasture feed" is a square circle; you're just wrong. In NZ, dairy is ~90% pasture, ~6 or 7% imported feed and ~3 or 4% local feed. Beef and sheep farms here use zero feed, or close to; the article only references dairy because it's implicit that only dairy uses much feed. Note that 10 years back, when the first dairy farm using feedlots opened (as opposed to using a bit of supplementary corn in winter / drought summer), it made front page news across the country; it's exceptional here.

Comment: @SeanOConnor your own source uses the term pasture feed, so you are now claiming your own source is wrong, which demonstrates you don't actually understand the terminology.  So since you have decided your own source is unsuitable , I will add a source, https://apps.fas.usda.gov/newgainapi/api/report/downloadreportbyfilename?filename=New%20Zealand%20Livestock%20Feed%20Situation%202017%20to%202020_Wellington_New%20Zealand_3-22-2018.pdf, note out of 5 million metric tons of feed used in NZ 3 million is imported, the single largest sector is for dairy cows.

Comment: See that first table in my source? 3 to 4 tonnes of pasture eaten per cow, some tiny fraction of feed eaten per cow. Those numbers only make any sense with pasture and feed as separate caregories. Bloviate or pretzel logic all you like, you're wrong.

Comment: @SeanOConnor you really should learn to read your sources, as you say lets start with the first table. Feed Demand  (tDM/cow)  3.94, pasture 3.77, everything else including crop and supplements add up to 0.16, if you add 3.77 and 0.16 you get 3.93 so pasture is a type of feed. It also openly states in the beginning paragraph it a study of non-pasture feeds and pasture feeds are grouped together regardless of source. As much fun as this tangent on the NZ dairy industry is, what do you think it has to do with fertility of agriculture?

Comment: How graceless. You've been going on about how most of the cows' food is imported and spouted rubbish. Then, when it turns out that 90%+ of what the cows consume is local grass, exactly as I said, you gracelessly won't admit you're wrong. A nation that provides 80% of the worlds exported milk and loads of meat almost entirely using pasture self evidently has very fertile land; very few dairying regions come close to self sufficiency.

Comment: "you can say that about any good farmland, which new Zealand has little of, and again the agricultural sector is productive because they produce mostly meat and dairy via imported feed. more than 60% of NZ animal feed is imported" - wrong.

Comment: @SeanOConnor, you've demonstrated cow mostly eat hay and silage, not where it comes from, and then only for dairy not even meats. You have not presented one shred of evidence to support your claim, while as I have provided several you have failed to even read. If you want to talk about grace, consider I have read and broken down your source and you have not read any of mine, of course it can't challenge your preconceived prejudices if you don' read anything so its understandable.

Answer (score 3):

[Mauritius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mauritius)

[image: forest]

https://www.veranda-resorts.com/blog/sensations-en/guide-to-the-mauritian-forest

A tropical paradise.  You can sleep on the beach.  Fruits and coconuts grow wild.

Also all true for Hawaii. Mauritius does have mosquitoes and precontact Hawaii didn't so that would be a plus for Hawaii.  But Mauritius had one thing Hawaii did not.

[image: ![dodo]

Yum!

Comment: But could you control the dodos using a twitch ;)

Comment: and then humans go extinct when they pull an easter island and use up all the boat making trees.

Comment: @SeanOConnor Oh no you're right. It's the ultimate predator.

Comment: @SeanOConnor  - Fixed.  But with love.

Answer (score 3):

### River delta with a harbour

What do Mesopotamia, Egypt, and ancient China all have in common? Starting on river deltas!

A big river brings lots of nice fresh water at low speeds. It's full of fish, and if it's not, you can still fish in the sea. There are lots of little islands and lots of wildlife of all types.

In addition, the plains around are full of beautiful, rich, silty alluvial soil, perfect for crops.

You can travel upstream quuckly or bring resources downstream by boat.

Just put a town on a small hillock (to avoid floods).

If the place has a harbour, it's even better.

I'd suggest looking for a continental, subtropical river delta but that's getting specific. If I had to pick one of the famous ones, I'd take Mesopotamia, with its dual river system (it seems like a good idea to double the main feature), but I don't really know.

Comment: Just clarifying: The Tigris and Euphrates only have one shared delta but do have separate catchments, etc.

Answer (score 2):

South-Eastern United States equivalent. Mild winters, plenty of water, not as hot as real tropics, usually.
The first written records of visitors to North America often commented on the sheer quantity, and size, of fish in the rivers. Numbers of other game animals.

Southern Europe, along the Mediterranean.

Other places in the world may be similar, but I don't know which.

Comment: The first European visitors were fishermen who brought diseases when they traded.  The East Coast was a flourishing fishing ground because the apex predator had been severely reduced.

Comment: Regardless, it's where indigenous population density was highest, right? So it's clearly hospitable.